# Changing the default MVC project template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, projects-and-solutions

I want to change the default project structure for a new mvc project. I have seen a webcast where Scott Guthrie does this but cannot find it. Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find ASP.NET MVC project templates under the following address:

> %VSPath%\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Web\1033\MvcWebApplicationProjectTemplatev2.0.cs.zip